# Cypress Spying on Vue components

Tags: vue.js, cypress, e2e-testing

I'm trying to write an e2e test using Cypress on my Vue app. I want to test if request on form submit returns correct value.
I know i need to use `cy.spy`. I also know I neet to spy on `fetch` method but I have no idea which object to tie it to.

From documantation:

> The `object` that has the method to be wrapped.

Which for me would be the component I'm trying to test? I'm not sure if I'm interpreting this argument correctly. Can anyone explain?

EDIT:
My guess is that I need to use `methods`? But if I try to import them into my `test_spec.js` I get `Cannot find module...`

Answer (score 0):

To spy over a response, you can use the route command instead of spy.
https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/route.html

```
it('Example Test', function () {
    cy.visit('https://stackoverflow.com/');
    cy.server(); // cy.server needs to be invoked first in order to use cy.route command
    cy.route({
        url: `**/your/request/path/**`,
        method: 'POST',
        onResponse: (xhr) => {
            console.log(xhr);
            // here you can assert on xhr.response.body values
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: If you want to catch `fetch` with `cy.route()` you need to turn on [Experimental Fetch Polyfill](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/06/29/experimental-fetch-polyfill/), presuming you are using an older version of Cypress. For the latest version change to `cy.intercept()`.